# Angular: Best way to set a default sort on a dynamic column in agGrid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm working on an agGrid, where we don't explicitly define the columns. I can't for the life of me figure out how to set a default sort on one of my columns. On init we do this:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = this.selectable ? this.getDefaultColumnsDefinition() : null;
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.getAllRefreshJobs();
}
```

It's one of the columns in `getDefaultColumnsDefinition()` that I want to be sorted initially. I tried

```
public onGridReady(params): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    const sortModel = [
        {colId: 'recordStartTime', sort: 'desc'}
    ];
    this.gridApi.setSortModel(sortModel);
    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

but it doesn't work. The grid looks the same. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what you have stated, you are calling the api before everything is initialized.  I'm not 100% sure how you have this set up, but you should make these adjustments in the `onGridReady` function of your code. Within onGridReady you can do something similar to this:

**HTML**

```
<ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="data"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

**TypeScript**

```
onGridReady(params): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    const sortModel = [
        {colId: 'recordStartTime', sort: 'desc'}
    ];
    this.gridApi.setSortModel(sortModel);
  }
```

This exposes the current gridApi and allows for you to make any post-initialization  modifications.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was just looking into onGridReady.... But it doesn't work. :-( I'll update my code to show you.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. As I walk through the debugger, I see the changes taking effect. But then something overwrites the column, and the options I specified get reset... But onGridReady is definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to @Jon Black for getting me started!

After I learned that **`setSortModel` is deprecated**, this is what worked for me:

```
function sortGrid(event, field, sortDir) {
  const columnState = { // https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-state/#column-state-interface
    state: [
      {
        colId: field,
        sort: sortDir
      }
    ]
  }
  event.columnApi.applyColumnState(columnState);
}
```

with

```
this.gridOptions = {
      defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true // enable sorting on all columns by default https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/
      },
      columnDefs,
      onGridReady: function (event) {
        console.log('The grid is now ready', event);
        sortGrid(event, 'timestamp', 'asc')
      },
    }
```

Comment: I landed here just now and was so thankful for this answer and then noticed the author. Ha. Thank you, past self.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be a good solution for you. But in `ColDef[]{` you can set the `sort: asc | desc` and set `initialSortIndex: 1 | 2`.

Example:

```
ColDef[] {
    return [
     ....
      {
        headerName: 'columnName1',
        field: 'columnField1',
        sort: 'desc',
        initialSortIndex: 1
      {
        headerName: 'columnName2',
        field: 'columnField2',
        sort: 'asc',
        initialSortIndex: 2
      },
    ...
 }
```

And in template part you can set the 'ctrl' key as key to use to multi sort in ag-grid like

```
<ag-grid-angular
...
[multiSortKey]="'ctrl'"
...
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into sorting ***grouped rows*** by default:

```js
  autoGroupColumnDef: ColDef = {
    field: 'yourFieldName',
    sort: 'orientation' // 'asc' or 'desc'
  };
```

```js
  this.gridOptions = {
    autoGroupColumnDef: this.autoGroupColumnDef
  };
```